# Can't successfully add a newline when I append text to a file

Tags: java, android, save, newline

I've created an app that creates a file on the device that stores about 5 values (double).  I think I'm writing the file successfully because I get to see a toast message on the device just after the file is written.

If I try and add a newline to the command, then I never see the toast message so the writing is failing.

Here is my WORKING code:

```
try{
            String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
            file = new File(path + "/" + filename);
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            for (int i = 0; i < priceArray.length; i++) {
                outputStreamWriter.append(String.format("%.2f", priceArray[i]));
                testText.append(String.format("%.2f", priceArray[i]));
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Prices saved successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is the best way to implement entries on their own line in the file?
The line testText.append(String.format("%.2f", priceArray[i])); in my code is there for me to see the values as I can't locate the file on the file system.

Comment: Please paste the output of logcat, i.e. add `Log.e("SOME_TAG", e.toString());` to the catch block.

Comment: How are you attempting to add the newline?

Comment: I've tried with appending this:  + "\r\n" to the string each time it writes.  Should I be doing that first?  I tried the line separator too, but that didn't work.

outputStreamWriter.append(String.format("%.2f", priceArray[i] + "\r\n"));

Maybe when I'm reading it back it is putting it into a single string.  I wish I could just find the file in explorer and open it up for viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format correctly:
outputStreamWriter.append(String.format("%.2f\n", priceArray[i]);
Notice \n after %.2f.

Comment: Thanks @krzdyn
I did what you said and now it successfully writes and gives the toast message.  Now I just have to read the file properly.  Thanks again!